# word choice: "obtain/acquire a flu vaccine" and "obtain/acqure a flu shot"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, collocations

(1a) Every winter, I get a flu shot.

(1b) Every winter, I receive a flu shot.

(1c) Every winter, I **obtain** a flu shot.

(1d) Every winter, I **acquire** a flu shot.

(2a) Every winter, I get a flu vaccine.

(2b) Every winter, I receive a flu vaccine.

(2c) Every winter, I **obtain** a flu vaccine.

(2d) Every winter, I **acquire** a flu vaccine.

Is it correct to replace both "get and receive" with either "obtain" or "acquire"?

Comment: A person would "get a flu shot" in idiomatic use. Listeners will understand that it was actually the vaccine, and not the flu itself. There are many grammatically correct sentences which sound odd because they are not in common use (or even make no logical sense).

Answer (score 3):

"Obtain" or "acquire" suggest you get the test tube, that contains the vaccine.  It doesn't suggest that you are inoculated with that vaccine.

So you might say "France has obtained/acquired the new flu vaccine from Poland."  or "My doctor has obtained 50 flu shots from the health service, and is offering them to the over-70s".   But it would be odd for an individual to obtain a flu shot.